# Ubuntu 11.10, Wireless Connection but no internet

Tags: 11.10, networking, wireless, internet, connection

Right after installing Ubuntu 11.10 using the wubi.exe file, I tried to surf the web in Ubuntu. My wireless connection is found without problem, but firefox doesn't manage to load any pages. Can somebody help me out? 
Please let me know which results of commands in the terminal I have to post.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

I have also the issue after installing `Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric)` on two `IBM T40` one with internal WiFi the other with NEC adapter, at the setup sequence the WiFi was working perfect, after restarting , the both PC WiFi got invalid gateway: `192.168.1.1` instead of `192.168.1.10` as my router is set. to resolves this issue at the moment I'd setup the adepter manually, very easy;

1. Right click on network icon,
2. Choose the WiFi you use (exp.HOME 1) go to `EDIT CONNECTION`
3. Choose wireless, take manual option , click `ADD`  fill the IP you
   give to you post (exp, 192.168.1.5) valid with ENTER; give mask
   (255.255.255.0), valid, give gateway of your router(exp.
   192.168.1.1).
4. now add the `DNS` ( open `CONNECTION INFORMATION` to see the `DNS` is
   available.)

I'd like to know why the WiFi adapters don't toll the good `GATEWAY`.